# Javascript adding class with transitions

Tags: javascript, callback, css-transitions

I have a test code like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .jeden {
      display: none;
      color: red;
      height: 0px;
    }
    
    .dwa {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .trzy {
      color: blue;
      opacity: 0.5;
      transition: all 2s;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="jeden"> Wczoraj </p>
  <button>ddd</button>
  <span id="hej">hej</span>
  <script>
    function dodaj(callback) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].classList.add("dwa");
      alert(1);
      alert(2);
      callback();
    }

    function dodajKlase() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].classList.add("trzy");
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
      dodaj(dodajKlase)
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

which I'm playing with, cause I don't understand a certain mechanism. In the above code the transition in `trzy` class works fine. But if I delete `alert(1)` and `alert(2)` the transition doesn't work.
Generaly, I'm trying to solve an issue:

1. Add a class with a `display: block` to an element - element appears,
2. Then add a class with `transitions` via callback function.

but this model doesn't work (I'm not quite sure I understand callback functions correctly in that case).

Comment: The alerts are halting execution so you can see it work.  Add some delays.

Answer (score 2):

You should force a `browser redraw` in your `dodaj` function, there are several ways to do it, one would be: `element.getBoundingClientRect()`

Read more about it here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .jeden {
      display: none;
      color: red;
      height: 0px;
    }
    
    .dwa {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .trzy {
      color: blue;
      opacity: 0.5;
      transition: all 2s;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="jeden"> Wczoraj </p>
  <button>ddd</button>
  <span id="hej">hej</span>
  <script>
    function dodaj(callback) {
      var element = document.querySelector("p.jeden");
      element.classList.add("dwa");
      element.getBoundingClientRect();

      callback();
      
    }

    function dodajKlase() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].classList.add("trzy");
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
      dodaj(dodajKlase)
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Little side note: You should force yourself to code in english, so other people can understand your function and variable names.

Comment: `You should force a browser redraw` - If you have a reference it will be great.

Comment: Added a link to some methods of forcing browser redraw and its explanation

Comment: Looks good! But can you explain why `setTimeout` with `0` ms works too? (I upvoted by the way :))

Comment: `setTimeout` with 0ms delays the excecution to a point where the current scope is done processing. Which allows the browser to redraw/repaint the style change, because the UI thread isn't blocked by any running JS.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the callback into a setTimeout() and it works.

```
function dodaj(callback) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].classList.add("dwa");
  setTimeout(callback, 100);
}
```

Comment: True, you could just use `0` too.